# KineticJS Layers Layering

Tags: html, html5-canvas, layer, kineticjs

I have one stage and 4-5 layers with images and shapes on every layer. Every time I add an object in a layer that layer takes a greater z-index , index and comes at the top of the other layers.


.moveToTop .setZIndex or other functions don't work on layers. I tested it with the latest version 4.3.0.

How can I define the z-index of the layers and stay that way each time I add/edit an object?


Please help.

Comment: Thank you @EliteOctagon, your answer is correct. But there is a problem with adding images. They are added after they are loaded. Images are always the last thing loaded, and they take the biggest index.

Answer (score 0):

When you first create the layers, you have:

```
layer1 = new Kinetic.Layer();
layer2 = new Kinetic.Layer();
```

Then you add them to the stage:

```
stage.add(layer1);
stage.add(layer2);
```

This adding to stage defines your z-index initially;

To change the index you have to do layer1.remove() to remove it from the stage and then add it again to bring it to the top.